# How can I grant a snap application access to /tmp via command line?

Tags: command-line, permissions, kubuntu, kde, snap

Is it possible to give a snap application access to the /tmp directory? Specifically, I want to be able to send email attachments directly to the application from Thunderbird. Granting access to my home directory is not enough as Thunderbird places files in /tmp when sending directly to an application. Since I am running Kubuntu 18.04, I don't have GUI controls over snaps & need a command line solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow snap applications to access /tmp folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263843/how-to-allow-snap-applications-to-access-tmp-folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every snap can access `/tmp/`, however, the `/tmp/` for every snap is actually a dedicated directory contained within the host's `/tmp/`, such that snaps can't access each others' `/tmp/`. As a result, Thunderbird can put files in `/tmp/`, but that's a different directory than the `/tmp/` seen by individual snaps. There are no interfaces of which I'm aware that allow for snaps to access the host's `/tmp/` directly, although [`browser-support` seems to allow access to `/var/tmp/`](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/master/interfaces/builtin/browser_support.go#L57) if that's at all helpful to you.